# assist with bootstrap responsive same height columns but with borders also

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have divs like a table and have it be responsive but also have the divs have a border. I have managed to do everything but have the borders. Here is my code:

```
<style>
  .row-eq-height {
      display: table;
      border-top: 1px solid #ccc; 
      background: white;
   }
  .row-eq-height > div {
      display: table-cell;
      padding: 20px;
   }
</style>

<div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12">
        <b>31103 ... Hospital Administration ... (Faculty only) ... (Administration)<font color="red">279053 (M.D.) ... 275531 (Ph.D.)</font></b>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12" >
        Administration of hospital laboratories and institutional administrative functions. Does not include medical school or
        University administrative functions. (See 11100 OR 31102)  ... 1% Effort variation must be reported
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 ">
        Clinical laboratory administration, Hospitals committee participation, service

        chief role, on-call time, indirect care, patient and physician consultation.
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12">
        Effort<br/><input type="text" name="p1" onblur="sum()" id="p1"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am struggling with having borders around the divs.  Nothing I have tried seems to work.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap? In BS4 the divs are equal height *out of the box* - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/yxjoBr

Comment: I believe it is bs 3; it is not the latest version - that is one of the problems but I am not able to affect that now; i am forced to work in the older environment